# Whats the best way to handle disabling legacy button with anchor?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm dealing with some legacy code that builds button from anchors and that's all done via custom tags (jsp).

I found out that there's a css class that disables the look of the button, but when i disable the button, even though it's "grayed out", still has the animation for push and the action is not prevented.

how do i prevent the animation?

Comment: Even if it _looks_ disabled, you will likely need to write javascript code to prevent the default behavior or set the _onclick_ or _href_ attributes to not respond to interaction.

Comment: I have figured out how to prevent the action from happening, but i dont know how to disable the animation of the button being pushed

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That would likely help us provide better responses.